# Is there a way to start multiple threads of Kafka listener which is defined only once through an API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka listener which is in a stopped state. I start it with an API call and it is stopped based on some internal condition. When I hit the API multiple times, I want multiple threads of it to run independently. Is there a way this can happen?
I am using Spring Kafka with SpringBoot.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `concurrency` property to get multiple threads. There must be at least as many partitions as the concurrency (only one consumer in a group can consume from a a partition at the same time).